# Wifi speed with driver rtl8187 drops

Tags: 10.04, wireless, kernel, drivers, realtek

I am using lucid lynx with [this USB adapter](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=es&tl=en&u=http://www.nisuta.com/producto.asp%3Fid%3DWIU54G55) and drivers rtl8187.

When I start a download, it starts at 1500kpbs (if i use "iwconfig wlan0 rate [more than 11MB]" it starts at a lower speed), it transfers a few kbs but then the speed starts to drop constantly and nothing is being transferred.

I've also tried the driver r8187, but I have the same speed problem only that with this driver the download starts at only 10kbps, and drops from there.

What can I try to identify the cause and fix this problem?

Comment: What is the network? What encryption?

Comment: Protocol:IEEE 802.11bg
Mode:Master
Channel:1
Encryption key:on
Bit Rates:54 Mb/s
Extra: Rates (Mb/s): 1 2 5.5 11 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54 
Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:158
Extra: Last beacon: 2ms ago

It also uses WEP.

Comment: Is the Access Point well-sited and proven (other devices have successfully used it)?

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.