# How can I tell which drivers are backported to stable kernels?

Tags: kernel, drivers

I was able to help [this person](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11015/wired-wireless-atheros-drivers-missing/11089#11089) by recommending the backported package of driver our kernel team provides. I had a hunch this would work because I happen to have the same hardware. I suspect it might be able to help [this person](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11336/wifi-speed-with-driver-rtl8187-drops) too however I am not sure which drivers get backported.

I did a `apt-get source linux-backports-modules-wireless-maverick-generic` but this just gives me a debian directory with the packaging with no indication of what drivers get included. Where can I find which drivers get backported?

Ideally I'd like to find a web page that has this information so I can refer to it for older releases as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're looking at the *meta package* for the modules. If you use `apt-cache show linux-backports-modules-wireless-maverick-generic | grep ^Depends` you can see what the actual package is that contains the modules. In this case, it's `linux-backports-modules-wireless-2.6.35-22-generic`

As for a webpage, the easiest is via [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/linux-backports-modules-wireless-2.6.35-22-generic), where you can keep clicking down to get the [list of files](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/amd64/linux-backports-modules-wireless-2.6.35-22-generic/filelist). Without a webpage, if it's already installed, you can use `dpkg -L linux-backports-modules-wireless-2.6.35-22-generic`